# How to use large volume of data in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm working with spark in python, trying to map PDF files to some custom parsing.  Currently I'm loading the PDFS with `pdfs = sparkContext.binaryFiles("some_path/*.pdf")`.
I set the RDD to be cachable on disk with `pdfs.persist( pyspark.StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK )`.

I then try to map the parsing operation.  And then to save a pickle But it fails with a out-of-memory error in the heap.  Could you help me please?

Here is the simplified code of what I do:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import pyspark

#There is some code here that set a args object with argparse.
#But it's not very interesting and a bit long, so I skip it.

def extractArticles( tupleData ):
    url, bytesData = tupleData
    #Convert the bytesData into `content`, a list of dict
    return content

sc = SparkContext("local[*]","Legilux PDF Analyser")

inMemoryPDFs = sc.binaryFiles( args.filePattern )
inMemoryPDFs.persist( pyspark.StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK )


pdfData = inMemoryPDFs.flatMap( extractArticles )
pdfData.persist( pyspark.StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK )
pdfData.saveAsPickleFile( args.output )
```

Comment: Which part actually fails? Does it work when you use `data.first()` / `data.count()`?

Comment: it failed on the `saveAsPickleFile`.  I didn't try to count.  It's currently running again with `data.persist(pyspark.StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)`

Comment: If so, please try that. It is rather unlikely that `saveAsPickleFile` is actually a failing part but it is a first action that triggers any computation.

Comment: I did, several times.  It absolutely changes nothing.  The mapping fails with an outOfMemory java error.  I edited the question to include a more exact code of what I do.

Comment: So if it fails during `flatMap` it means it is not related to saving.  There are [some many questions on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[apache-spark]+outOfMemory) about a proper Spark configuration you should easily find your solution.

Comment: Thank you for the correct search terms for all the questions.  However there seems to be a common pattern of having large input and small output.  I have large input and large output.  I believe saving tries to `collect()` first or something alike, and then fails due to the size of the data.

Comment: `RDD.saveAs*` methods don't collect the data. Each partition is saved directly by the respective worker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91744/discussion-between-zero323-and-laerne).